# Why does Spyder "variables information" show wrong shapes of NumPy arrays in a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I made a dictionary that consists of arrays.

The thing is the size of each array seems to be wrong according to the result of SPYDER editor windows... it looks switched.

```py
import numpy as np
   
network = {}
network['W1'] = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]])
network['b1'] = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

It is true that network['W1'] size(shape) is (2, 3) and another is (3,).
However my windows(from SPYDER editor) shows wrong size.

I attached a screenshot of what I see, and you can also see the size of `network['W1']` is (3,)
and `network['b1']` is (2,3).

Anyone knows what is happenening here?

[image]

Comment: I can't prove it right now but I'm very certain that what you have written is not true. Are you sure that you haven't mixed up `W1` and `b1`? What code did you run for "you can find size"?

Comment: the size of network['W1'] should be (2,3) not (3,). Is it wrong?

Comment: You said it's (3,) but it should be (2,3). Yes, it should be (2,3). Why do you think it is (3,)?

Comment: Because it (python) show me like that. and that is my question.

Comment: What's that window that is titled "network"?

Comment: Attached image is from SPYDER and window is variables information window.

Comment: What do you get if you close all windows and run the code again?

Comment: I found that it doesn't fixed if I restart. However it shows correct result when I type network['W1'].shape(). I guess the problem is due to SPYDER WINDOWS.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You guessed correctly. This was caused by a bug in Spyder but it's fixed now. Please update by opening the Anaconda Prompt and running there `conda update anaconda` and then `conda install spyder=4.2.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Spyder maintainer here) This problem was caused by a bug in Spyder but it's fixed now. Please update by opening the Anaconda Prompt and running there

```
conda update anaconda
```

and then

```
conda install spyder=4.2.5
```

Comment: What was the bug? Did it swap the keys in a dictionary? Did it display old information that was not updated correctly when the variables changed? Was it specific to NumPy?

Comment: The bug was caused because we were not sorting keys in our dictionary viewer correctly.